# Corregir error al consultar WebService, axios, javascript?

Tags: javascript, axios

Buena tarde debo realizar una consultar con el método axios.get, pero me da el siguiente mensaje:

```
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://URL/api/Metodo'."
}
```

lo estoy intentando resolver de la siguiente forma:

```
var nueva_url = encodeURI('https://URL/api/Metodo');

    obtenerAsignaciones(nueva_url);
         function obtenerAsignaciones(nueva_url) {
            myApp.showIndicator();
             return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                axios.get(nueva_url, {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: token_type + " " + access_token
                    }
                }).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    myApp.hideIndicator();
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                })
            })
        }
```

Pero me sigue generando el mismo mensaje

Que podrá ser?
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Tu servidor soporta httpS?

Comment: En realidad Si, lo que veo que con otro metodo que me daba el mismo mensaje le aplique la funcion encodeURI y ahi ya me dejo pasar.

Comment: Entonces, ¿el problema fue resuelto?